# Java JEditorPane displaying html image issue

Tags: java, html, swing, bufferedimage, jeditorpane

I have been working to convert HTML to image using Java. But am facing an issue with loading image from like HTML tag:

```html
<img src="http://url.png" ..
```

Like image not loaded: 
[issue link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6XDo.png)

Comment: Don't repost questions. The other question was closed because you did not provide an [mre]. A partial line of code does not tell use what you are doing.